# Does Silence stop working in the Cleanup step, allowing more spells to cast in the same turn when discard triggers effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In a recent CEDH game of [Playing With Power MTG](https://youtu.be/B2EGuv3GjeM?t=394), one player played [Silence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Silence) during the turn of a [The Gitrog Monster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Gitrog%20Monster) player. The Gitrog player then uses the Dredgmooor combo in his endstep and afterwards plays spells with the understanding that the effect of the Silence ended in the cleanup state and they can play more spells that turn.

Is this a valid play?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes, the play was legal.**

Normally, during the cleanup step, no player gets priority to cast spells or activate abilities. However, since the player affected by Silence controlled [The Gitrog Monster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Gitrog%20Monster) and had to discard cards during cleanup, one of which was a land, players got rounds of priority. By that time, Silence had already ended and that player was allowed to cast spells.

> 514. Cleanup Step

> 514.1. First, if the active player’s hand contains more cards than their maximum hand size (normally seven), they discard enough cards to reduce their hand size to that number. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.

The Gitrog player discarded 3 cards here. One of them was a land ([Mana Confluence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mana%20Confluence)), so the Gitrog Monster ability triggered and was waiting to enter the stack.

> 514.2. Second, the following actions happen simultaneously: all damage marked on permanents (including phased-out permanents) is removed and all “until end of turn” and “this turn” effects end. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.

Silence ended here.

> 514.3. Normally, no player receives priority during the cleanup step, so no spells can be cast and no abilities can be activated. However, this rule is subject to the following exception:

> 514.3a At this point, the game checks to see if any state-based actions would be performed and/**or any triggered abilities are waiting to be put onto the stack** (including those that trigger “at the beginning of the next cleanup step”). If so, those state-based actions are performed, then those triggered abilities are put on the stack, then the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities. Once the stack is empty and all players pass in succession, another cleanup step begins.

The Gitrog Monster's ability entered the stack here and players get rounds of priority, allowing everyone to cast spells.

Answer (score 10):

Yes (surprisingly).

Three things happen in the Cleanup Step in order:

1. The active player discards to hand size.
2. Damage is removed **and "this turn" effects end**.
3. If any state-based actions would be performed and/or triggered abilities are waiting to happen, they happen.

Because the triggers happen after point 2, "this turn" effects have ended and so Silence's effect no longer applies.

[Comprehensive Rules 514](https://media.wizards.com/2021/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020210419.pdf):

> 514. Cleanup Step
>
> 514.1. First, if the active player’s hand contains more cards than their maximum hand size (normally seven), they discard enough cards to reduce their hand size to that number. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.
>
> 514.2. Second, the following actions happen simultaneously: all damage marked on permanents (including phased-out permanents) is removed and all “until end of turn” and “this turn” effects end. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.
>
> 514.3. Normally, no player receives priority during the cleanup step, so no spells can be cast and no abilities can be activated. However, this rule is subject to the following exception:
>
> 514.3a At this point, the game checks to see if any state-based actions would be performed and/or any triggered abilities are waiting to be put onto the stack (including those that trigger “at the beginning of the next cleanup step”). If so, those state-based actions are performed, then those triggered abilities are put on the stack, then the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities. Once the stack is empty and all players pass in succession, another cleanup step begins.